# Volcanic 3D masyu

Tags: grid-deduction, three-dimensional, masyu

This is a three-dimensional masyu puzzle. The six squares depict the layers of a $6\times6\times6$ cube. The goal is to make a single loop in 3D space which fulfills the following properties:

- The line passes through centres of cells and makes 90-degree turns only.
- The line cannot cross itself or branch off in multiple directions.
- The line passes through every white and black circle.
- When passing through a white circle, the line must go straight through the circled cell and make a turn directly before or after that cell (or both).
- When passing through a black circle, the line must make a turn in the circled cell and continue straight for at least one cell on both sides.
- Red squares are lava. No line passes through lava.

**Note**: Feel free to use any notation you feel the most comfortable with, as long as it's properly explained. [My way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3oGT.png) is to use diagonal lines to show movement between layers.

> [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is

> [image]

Explanation:

> We can go a long way looking at just the white circles. The ones in a corner must go in/out, and the ones near an edge must go parallel to that edge if they cannot go in/out (e.g. if they are on layer #1 or #6).
>
>  Once we have those filled out we can use what we've filled out to deduce even more white circles, including some places where the line must turn:
>  [image]
>
>
>  At this point we'll start looking at the black circles. Since these require at least 1 straight piece in each of its two directions, we can deduce a lot of them especially on layer #2 and #5. Some of them we know exactly (when they only have 2 valid directions) or we might know one of their directions (when they have 3 valid directions, 2 of which are on an axis, meaning we are certain of the third):
>  [image]
>
>
>  As we keep working on these we find a few places where the paths that a line could take are blocked off by the lines above/below it. Namely we can solve (almost) all of layer #1:
>  [image]
>
>
>  At this point it's mostly a matter of working our way down layer by layer, solving as many circles as we can. One notably different piece of logic is that we can deduce the top-left corner of layer #2, since it cannot go in and is entirely enclosed on layers #2 and #1 - this means that it must go out onto layer #1 and immediately back into layer #2:
>  [image]
>
>
>  Nothing much of interest happens until we've finished solving the cube. It's simply a matter of repeatedly finding a circle that we can deduce the solution for, and then using the cells that are solved by this to further deduce new circles, or deduce the path of open lines.
>  Eventually all layers are solved and we have the completed cube. A full list of steps can be found [at this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtJFu.jpg)

Comment: This is correct. Nice work!

Comment: @jafe This was fun to solve :) I have no idea how you make these puzzles so they're both uniquely solveable and require multiple kind of deductions, but you somehow do. Great puzzle!

Comment: Glad you liked it! Often the difficult part is trying to not blow a fuse when I'm almost done, realize I left a contradiction in step 1 and have to start over.